# centOS: full file system backup and restoration

Tags: centos, filesystems, backup, restore, dump

I have a dedicated server with **centOS**. I need to do a **full system backup**, save backup file on server and download a copy of that backup file to my personal computer (local computer in office).

From what I have read the tools to use are either `dump` or `rsync`.

**1.Step:** make file system backup via `dump` -> save as compressed `gz` file

**2.Step**: download the `gz` file to my local pc(windows)

**3.Step:** On later time, if centOS is corrupted/broken/hacked -> upload `gz` file to server and restore whole system via this backup file

How can this be achieved ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If it is just filesystems, there are many tools.  Rsync through SSH is a simple start.

For a whole system, look at Clonezilla.